# PHP for each loop photo fields from value

Tags: php, for-loop

I am trying to create a for each loop where a new file input field is created depending on how many items have been selected. Code below.

This gets the number of items that have been selected. Values range from 1 to 10.

```
$items = $_GET['item'];
```

This is what I would like to be dynamically looped through for the number of items selected.

```
<input type="file" name="photo1" />
```

I need `name="photo1"` to increase by one every time depending on how many items are selected.

I don't really know how to write this but this is what I have tried so far.

```
foreach($items as $item) {
        $item = '<input type="file" name="photo'. $item + 1 .'" />';
}
```

This doesn't work and that is no surprise because I don't really know how to write this. Can anyone help me out with this please?

Many thanks in advance, Harry

Comment: you are using the wrong loop, try `for()`. `foreach()` is for an array, you ave an integer value

Comment: As @Dagon suggested, use for ($item=1; $item<=$items; $item++) instead of foreach($items as $item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, You can use [for](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop

```
for($i=1; $i<=$items; $i++) {
    echo $item = '<input type="file" name="photo'. $i .'" />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` is designed to loop over arrays. You just want a simple `for` loop:

```
for (i=0; i < $items; i++){
 echo '<input type="file" name ="photo'.$i.'"/>';
}
```